# How can I close a port (seen open on netstat)?

Tags: macos, mac, port, netstat

I used netstat and I see some ports open that I want closed. How do I close them?

The computer is a Mac running OS X

Comment: you should ask this question in superuser

Comment: `netstat -lp` will give you process/port

Comment: ... did not work ... Mac OSX

***

Comment: http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Port_to_PID_with_lsof.html, http://sial.org/howto/debug/unix/lsof/

Answer (score 4):

Try using

> lsof | grep *portnumber*

to get the process that has it opened.

You could also use the `-i` option to let `lsof` do the filtering for a TCP port

> lsof -i TCP:*portnumber*